# maven-jar-plugin and excluding transitive dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar, transitive-dependency

I'm creating some additional jar file in my pom.xml of a big project (basically, some model classes)

I'm using the maven-jar-plugin with this configuration:

```
                <execution>
                    <id>issue-models-jar</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        </archive>
                        <classifier>issue-models</classifier>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/api/issues/models/**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

This gives me nice clean jars. However, when I use these jars as dependencies in another project (after installing them in a repo), the dependencies of the 'mother' pom also appear.

I know I can exclude these depedencies, but I don't want to do that in each project where I use these jars.

Is such a thing feasable in maven? Or am I just taking the wrong approach(tm)?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible - the transitive dependencies are the result of the pom hierarchy, not your custom jar. While you could try to concoct something using the `dependencyManagement` section in the 'mother' pom, this will likely just move the problem and so I think the best option would be to break out the 'models' into their own project with their own pom and then depend on this new artifact (project) from the existing project and wherever else as needed.

Comment: If you have a separate intention for reuse i would strongly recommend to make a separate module which contains only those model classes and use the defaut to package your jar file ... which includes the dependencies (defined in the pom file) and that separate module you can configure in the way you need to...